# Remote Control an Apple iPad

Tags: remote-desktop, ios, ipad

It's 2017 and a lot of info on this is pretty dated.  I've heard TeamViewer can, then it seems like it can only control your app.

Anyway I got my parents an iPad for Xmas.  They know nothing about computers.  I need something I can use to remote in and help them (preferably free).  If I have to set up a vpn and host some kind of software it's not a big deal.  Since they don't have a computer I can not use QuickTime.  It has to be one click easy for them.

Comment: Asked twice yesterday on [ask different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Remote into an iPad, that's not happening, blame Apple for their design philosophy

Comment: @Ramhound how do big companies support them then?

Comment: They don't remote into them

Comment: @Ramhoubd I suppose I could create a VPN between our house.  If I do it as a TAP I could bridge l2 together so that ARD will work.  Is that a viable solution?

Comment: @BloomingtonABS7 the network doesn't matter, you can't remote control an iPad without jailbreaking and running a VNC server.  In simple terms the iPad sandboxes every app from everything else, and apple won't accept apps that break their rules.

Comment: @Tyson Hmm I guess an IP camera will have to do or Apple TV mirror over vpn

Comment: You'd be amazed how little remote support an iDevice needs. I swapped my 80+ year-old parents from a WinXP machine to 2 iPads 2 iPhones & an iMac. I used to have to remote into the XP machine about once a week, I've not needed to remote to the iDevices once in 2 years. A quick poke around everything every 6 months or so when I go over there [4000 miles] is sufficient.